# how to reset password for 15000 user and send it to the email id in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email, password

i got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 41: parser error : StartTag:
>   invalid element name in public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 383' in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2,
>   'simplexml_load_...', '/p...', 383, Array) #1
>   /public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(383):
>   simplexml_load_string('loadCache() #3
>   /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(255):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache() #4
>   /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(277):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->init(Array) #5 /public_html/app/Mage.php(616):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array) #6
>   /public_html/sendmail.php(6): Mage: in
>   /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245

Using this script

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',true);
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Mage::app();

$coll = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

$coll->addFieldToFilter('group_id',1);


foreach ($coll as $customer) {
$customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
$sendPassToEmail = true;
$customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword());
$customer->save();
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '',
$customer->getStoreId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this isn't real fix of your issue but, as it is still a warning, not real fatal error (this fatal is due to uncaught exception), you can temporary hide xml warnings by using this line right after ini_set

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Question: why you don't use shell script extending Mage_Shell_Abstract class?
It's easy to implement only one method run().

Comment: can you give me a example for send bulk email to all users

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fan of bulk mailing 15k unique customers using Zend_Mail but here you go:

```
    /** Returns mail transport object
     * @param $email
     * @param $name
     * @param $templateId
     * @param $emailTemplateVariables
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer
     */
    protected function getMailObj($email, $name, $templateId, $emailTemplateVariables = array())
    {
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($email, $name);
        /** @var $mailObject Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
        $mailObject = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        $mailObject->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        $mailObject->setSender(
            array(
                'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'),
                'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name')
            )
        );
        $mailObject->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailObject->setTemplateParams($emailTemplateVariables);

        return $mailObject;
    }

    /** Send new email
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer
     */
    public function sendEmail($email, $name, $surname, $mailTemplateId)
    {
        $mail = $this->getMailObj(
            $email,
            $name . ' ' . $surname,
            $mailTemplateId,
            // these are optional parameters passed to your email template
            /*
            array(
                'test1' => 'testa',
                'test2' => 'testb'
            )
            */
        );

        return $mail->send();
    }
```

Where $mailTemplateId is your email template Id created in magento backend. To add another email to queue use: addEmailInfo method before sending.